# Sorting of data

Tags: iphone

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:globalManagedObjectContext];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
   NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
  fetchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[globalManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortByName release];
  return fetchResults;
```

follow case sensitiveness. Uppercase is on top.

```
Ab
Ba
a.
```

like above. Please give any solution for ignoring case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score -1):

NSSortDescriptor *authorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"author" ascending:YES];